# What type of animal is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arthropod

There was a leaking fire hydrant across a sidewalk. On the other side was a lake. The fire hydrant water was streaming across the sidewalk.

I saw it swimming in the sidewalk away from the side of the lake to the fire hydrant.

What is it?[image]

Comment: Could you give us some idea of scale, it's about 18 cm long on my computer screen, I'm sure that's not right.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Identifications questions should include: 1) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; 2) the species-identification tag; and 3) an estimate of the size of the organism. Click on or hover over the 'species-identification' tag for details. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Likely a dragonfly larva, but I don't know the specific type. They live in water and eat anything they catch like small fish.

Comment: This is incorrect. It's a mole cricket

Comment: They live in water ?

Comment: They do not. They live underground. Likely flooded out of its underground hole and seen seeking drier ground. (Alternatively, it could have already been aboveground and just gotten caught in the deluge).

Comment: I must agree with you , but I made a close guess.

Comment: Second: This is not a dragon fly instar.